# Invalid policy or invalid arg type on AWS cloudfront getSignedCookies using custom policy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to create a custom policy for **getSignedCookies**, but I am not clear on what format the policy should have.

This is my code:

```js
  import { getSignedCookies } from "@aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer";


  let originalString = process.env.S3_PRIVATEKEY_CLOUDFRONT;
  let privateKey = originalString.replace(/\\n/g, "\n");
  const keyPairId = "XXXXXXXXXX";
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var oneHourFromNow = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
  const dateLessThan = oneHourFromNow;

  const policy = {
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Resource": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/harry/*",
        "Condition": {
          "DateLessThan": {
            "AWS:EpochTime": dateLessThan.getTime(),
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  };

  const signedCookie = getSignedCookies({
    keyPairId,
    policy,
    privateKey,
  });
  return signedCookie;
```

This is returning me an error : `error - TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of Object` on getSignedCookies function.

To fix this, I tried parsing the policy constant to a string:

```js
...
  const stringPoly = JSON.stringify(policy);
  const signedCookie = getSignedCookies({
    keyPairId,
    stringPoly,
    privateKey,
  });
...
```

but I received `error - Error: Invalid policy`

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Your policy seems correct. You are not supplying URL and dateLessThan parameters into getSignedCookies function.

```
return getSignedCookies({url:url,privateKey:privateKey,keyPairId:keyPairId,dateLessThan:expiry,policy:policyString});
```